# ZF2: The target-entity cannot be found in 'Application\Entity\ #user'

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, entity

I'm using Zend Framework 2 with Doctrine2.
I use a User and Project entity. A user can have more projects and a project can have multiple users. So i use another entity User_Project.
They are all set up and I've validated the schema. All mapping files are correct and the database schema is in sync (orm:validate-schema).
When I try to get all my users, I get an error that the target entity cannot be found (see title). Same error when I try getting one user.

**ERROR**

> The target-entity Application\Entity\User_Project cannot be found in 'Application\Entity\User#user'.

**Controller:**

`return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->findAll();`

**User entity**

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity 
*   @ORM\Table(name="user")
**/
class User {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="user_id")
*/
protected $user_id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $fullName;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User_Project", mappedBy="user") */
protected $user;

public function getUserId()
{
    return $this->user_id;
}

public function getFullName()
{
    return $this->fullName;
}

public function setFullName($value)
{
    $this->fullName = $value;
}
}
```

**Project entity**

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity 
@ORM\Table(name="project")
**/

class Project {
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
* @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="project_id")
*/
protected $project_id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $customer;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
protected $project_name;

/** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User_Project", mappedBy="project") */
private $project;

public function getProjectId()
{
    return $this->project_id;
}

}
```

**User_Project entity**

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity 
*   @ORM\Table(name="user_project")
**/
class User_Project {

/** 
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="user") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $user;

/** 
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="project") 
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="project_id", nullable=false) 
 */
protected $project;


public function getUser()
{
    return $this->project;
}

public function getProject()
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser($value)
{
    $this->user = $value;
}

public function setProject($value)
{
    $this->project = $value;
}
}
```

**Modules.php**

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a extra entity (User_Project) for what actually is just a ManyToMany relationship?

Comment: It's possible User_Project gets another column like 'function'.
Also, I started with a ManyToMany relationship, but I got way to many errors

Comment: Still think it should be a relation not a separate entity. The column function would be specific to the User or the Project not to the relation they have to each other right? Getting way to many errors is not really a valid reason not to use a manyToMany relation..

Comment: But your current problem can most likely be solved by using: targetEntity="Application\Entity\User_Project"

Comment: Nope, already tried that but it gives me the same error.
A user could have different functions according to the project, so it's project specific function

Answer (score 1):

may definition of your entity in Module.php or module.config.php is wrong .
please copy Module.php or module.config.php

correct definition in module.config.php:

```
return array(
'doctrine' => array(
    'driver' => array(
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
        ),
        'orm_default' => array(
            'drivers' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
))))),
```

in user Entity may be better rename user property to userProjects or projects and apply change on relation definition on User_Project

Comment: i am sorry for change answer . i am new to stackoverflow .

Comment: @ORM\Id() in user_project should not be exist on user and project properties

Comment: Changed it to userProjects, same error:
The target-entity Application\Entity\User_Project cannot be found in 'Application\Entity\User#userProjects'.

Answer (score 0):

check your column names in database . if you want have correct db . i recommend schema tool for create db .

```
$tool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($this->getEntityManager());
$classes = array(
     $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata('Application\Entity\User'),
     $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata('Application\Entity\Project'),
     $this->getEntityManager()->getClassMetadata('Application\Entity\User_Project'),
);

$tool->dropSchema($classes);
$tool->createSchema($classes);
```

in a controller or somewhere else .

Comment: I used doctrine cli to create my db with: ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create and update. I added your code, no problems performing it, but I get the same error afterwards

Comment: may you have bad data . in user_project table column user_id is null in a record . set nullable=true and check.

Comment: test it with lazy fetch http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html  and see error happen again . in this state user_project don't try load user.